# Javascript str.search("?") returns Unexpected Quantifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to search a string using `str.search("me");` and `str.search("=");`

But when i serach for `str.search("?");`

I get the error `Unexpected Quantifier.`

Why is that?
How can i search for `"?"` using something other than a regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alert(str.indexOf("?")); // returns position as integer if present, -1 otherwise
```

Typical usage scenario is:

```
if(str.indexOf("?") !== -1) {
    // present
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 6):

"?" is a special character in a regular expression (one of the "quantifiers") which means "match the preceding zero or one times". It lead to the error in this case because it was preceded by nothing. However, "a?" wouldn't have thrown an exception, but would match "b" so this is an important thing to look out for.

If using `String.search`, which takes a regular expression (as karim79 points out, it isn't the only way), use `"[?]"` or `"\\?"` or `/\?/`. These forms will prevent the "?" from being treated as a special regular expression construct.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert(str.search("\\?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quantifier and you can`t directly use it. From [javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

> **?** is short for {0,1}. Matches zero or one time.
>
> and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/193ztwkw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)
>
> **?** Matches the preceding character or subexpression zero or one
>   time. For example, 'do(es)?' matches the "do" in "do" or "does". ? is
>   equivalent to {0,1}

This is the right usage:

```
str.search("\\?")
```